# How to write a generic function to compute recursive combination

Tags: c++, generics, recursion, combinations

For example:

<1,2,3> as an input to the function comb  to get combination of 2 elements will output result <<1,2>,<1,3>,<2,3>>, which as input to same function will get 
<<<1,2>,<1,3>>,<<1,3>,<2,3>>,<<1,2>,<2,3>>, which as input to the same function will get
....

Logic is the same, only type changes, so it can be made generic.
I tried to write something like this:

```
template<typename V>
vector<vector<vector<V>::const_iterator>> comb(const vector<V>){
   ....

   while(next_combination(...))
   vector<vector<vector<V>::const_iterator>> results;
   return results;
}

vector<string> input
comb(comb(comb(input)));
```

But compiler keep complaining can't deduce the returning value's type.

Thanks.

Comment: You should post the exact code (at least the signature of the template) and the exact error code.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Sorry, code already messed up, to make my job done, I already replace those code in my project to several quick dirty  comb functions.

Comment: Actually you should need a whitespace between two `>` inside a template for a template declaration. there is a difference between `>>` and `> >`. I wonder why your compiler does not complain.

Comment: Voting to close, without the *real code* and the *compiler errors* it is impossible to answer, and additionally it seems that you no longer needed (you might want to *close* the question yourself)

Comment: @Papergay: If using a C++11 compiler, it will be handled properly.

Comment: `vector<V>::const_iterator` is a dependent name, so needs to be qualified with `typename`.  Not that it makes much sense to return a vector containing iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following will help:

```
template <typename T>
vector<vector<T> > comb(vector<T> v)
{
    vector<vector<T> > result;
    // may want to sort the input vector before iterating over the combinations
    do {
        result.push_back(v);
    } while (next_combination(...));
    return result;
}
```

Note the changes:

- The return value of `comb` is a vector of vectors
- The parameter of `comb` is not `const` because `next_combination` changes it
- There is much copying of vectors inside `comb`; all that copying seems necessary

Comment: The above code works, thanks. Why I used const_iterator is to avoid copy the content for permutation or combination again and again, that part **vector<T>::const_iterator** seems to rely on return type deduction, that's why my code didn't work.